# Binding Weblogic WorkManager using SERVICEGEN

Tags: web-services, configuration, ant, weblogic, workmanagers

For some reasons, we want to add a WEB-LOGIC configured work-manager into *web-services.jar* which is being generated by ANT Script using *servicegen* tag. Yes, we can try it using *weblogic-ejb.jar* but it has some other concerns. Is there a way, taht we can bind work-managers to these services?

```
<servicegen destEar="${release_env}/project.ear"
                warName="webservices.war"
                contextURI="webservices"
                keepGenerated="True">
        <service
                ejbJar="${ear}/project-ejb.jar"
                includeEJBs="ProjectRequestBean"
                targetNamespace="http://localhost/services/WS1"
                serviceName="WS1"
                serviceURI="/WS1"
                generateTypes="True"
                expandMethods="True">
        </service>
        <service
                ejbJar="${ear}/project-ejb.jar"
                includeEJBs="ModuleRequestBean"
                targetNamespace="http://localhost/services/WS2"
                serviceName="WS1"
                serviceURI="/WS2"
                style="document"
                generateTypes="True"
                expandMethods="True">
        </service>
    </servicegen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servicegen task does not seem to support an option which allows you configure a work-manager. After generating the ear file, you can open up project.ear -> webservices.war -> WEB-INF/weblogic.xml and add an entry like the following. This overrides the default work-manager for all the requests being serviced by the 'webservices' context-uri.

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
   <param-value>my_workmanager</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You can fine tune the settings as described in 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13701/self_tuned.htm#CNFGD112

You can also use weblogic deployment plans to set the above work-manager setting. That way you dont have to  manually open up the ear and update weblogic.xml. More information about deployment plans can be found at 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13702/config.htm#DEPGD169